# How to use react-native-fetch-blob for making directories and paths

Tags: javascript, react-native

Am trying to use react-native-fetch-blob to create directories and paths.
How do i use it? i try to use this but i cant find the directory i created.

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir(PATH_TO_CREATE)
.then(() => { ... })
.catch((err) => { ... })
```

But when i console the list of directories, i cant find it.

```
const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
console.log(dirs)
```

i try to console the directory but i cant find it.
Also how to do i use the 'createFile' Command.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. Try this:
Suppose you need to create a folder named 'Unread_Books'.

```
    const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs; //Use the dir API
    const Unread_Books = dirs.DocumentDir + '/Unread_Books';
    RNFetchBlob.fs
      .mkdir(Unread_Books)
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    console.log(dirs.DocumentDir);
    console.log(Unread_Books);
```

Also check docs for further reference, https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#assetfilenamestringstring .

For create file refer here, [How to create a file and store it inside download folder android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474416/how-to-create-a-file-and-store-it-inside-download-folder-android) .