# How to create a file and store it inside download folder android?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am using `rn-fetch-blob` https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob I am creating new file and storing it inside downloads folder. Note: I am using emulator.  Now when I try to create a new file and I am using download dir see this -> https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#dirs but I am getting error saying permission denied why so ? How can I enable permission so that file gets stored inside download folder in android react native app ?

Code:

```
saveFile = () => {
        const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;

        const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
        console.log("directory path: ",dirs.DownloadDir );

        const NEW_FILE_PATH = dirs.DownloadDir + '/demo.txt';

        console.log("file path: ", NEW_FILE_PATH);

        fs.createFile(NEW_FILE_PATH, 'foo', 'utf8');

    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For allowing acccess to other dirs in rn-fetch-blob if android version is above 6 then you need to ask for runtime permission. Link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid

Modified code:

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

    saveFile = async () => {

            try {
                const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                );
                if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                    console.log("Permission granted");

                    const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
                    // const base64 = RNFetchBlob.base64;

                    const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
                    console.log(dirs.DownloadDir);

                    const NEW_FILE_PATH = dirs.DownloadDir + '/test.txt';
                    fs.createFile(NEW_FILE_PATH, 'foo', 'utf8');

                } else {
                    console.log('Permission denied');
                }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.warn(err);
                }

        }
```

Additional links for rn-fetch-blob:

1) https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#dirs

2) https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob

Comment: Hi, I am getting Unhandled Promise rejection with this code.? Please help. I am trying to write file to Downloads folder.

Answer (score 3):

you need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

If you are using android 6 version or higher you need to ask for runtime permission

Comment: I am using android 9 API 28

Comment: I have added those 2 lines inside androidManifest.xml file but still getting same issue why so ?

Comment: ok just go to app settings then permission ,give storage permission and try

Comment: @kritika Ok fixed the issue. For react native android you don;t need to add uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> these lines. See my modified answer.